# Using a while loop to iterate through user input until specific number

Tags: c

I am trying to print out each integer on a new line, given integers separated by whitespace from a user input. It stops printing after a specific number, lets say 84. For example

The user input is

```
20 -4 84 8
```

How could i use a while loop to print these out as

```
20
-4
84
```

i know about scanf("%d %d %d %d", a, b, c, d), However the input size would be unknown, such that there could be only 3 numbers or 7 numbers. So far i have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while (x != 84) {
        print("%d\n", x[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `num`? Do you want to store the previous numbers?

Comment: sorry editing the question. it is the 'x' which is the user input. No not looking to store previous numbers, just needing to print them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Push the `scanf` into the `while` condition. Something like

```
while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF && x != 84)
    print("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: +1 for checking the return value of scanf, to avoid inf-loop when user enters something that "%d" won't scan.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed. Could you explain to me how putting the scanf inside the while condition works compared to what i was doing? I am new to C, thanks

Comment: @Jack8246 You scanned for input once and compared to `84` again and again, this scans until `84` is found. That's the difference. This also checks if scanf correctly reads what it is asked to, `int` here.

Comment: @Shreevardhan I see, so by putting the scanf into the while loop, does the while loop automatically iterate through each integer from the user input? This is the main thing I'm not sure about, hence why i had the 'i++' in my previous code

Comment: @Jack8246 Yes. `scanf("%d", &x);` scans an integer in `x`. Putting this inside a loop condition will execute it in every loop iteration until the loop breaks. So, it scans integers until it finds `84`. You can read a good book on C programming to get better idea.

Comment: this does not properly handle the case when scanf() returns EOF

Comment: How @user3629249 ? In `C`, `EOF` is `-1`. It should work.

Comment: @user3629249 Nevertheless, added the EOF check. THanks.

Answer (score 2):

The basic concept should be of two-steps:

1. Read the number
2. Check and decide whether to print /continue.

A psuedo-code would look like

```
while ((ret =scanf(x)) && ret != EOF ){
     if (x == VAL) break;
     printf(x);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors:

- the array `num` does not exist;
- the `scanf` must be repeated inside the while loop.

The corrected code is thw following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    while( 1 ){
        scanf( "%d", &x );
        print( "%d\n", x );
        if( x==84 ) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the array num was supposed to be 'x', sorry about that. Thanks for the answer

Comment: this answer is almost right; however, the OP indicated the 84 was to be printed. so the 'if()' statement and the printf() statement need to be swapped. BTW: it is 'printf' not 'print' and the returned value (not the parameter value) also needs to be checked, so something like a user input that is not digits, like a simple newline and/or a...z, etc can be caught, when the returned value is not 1, need a call to getchar() rather than a call to printf() and if returned value is EOF, then need to exit loop

Answer (score -1):

You need to put `scanf()` inside the `while` loop in order to update every new input. No need for arrays if you want to print only the inputted values because you can print it after new input. Better do it with `do-while` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;

    do {
        if ( scanf("%d", &x) < 0 )
            break;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    } while (x != 84);
}
```